# Unexpected behavior in Common Lisp type specifiers

Tags: types, common-lisp

I just read up on types in CL and I find the following behavior e.g. concerning subsidiary type information on the vector type a bit puzzling:

```
(let ((v1 (vector 1 3))
      (v2 (vector 1 3 4))
      (v3 (vector 1 3 "4")))
  (values
   (typep v1 '(vector (satisfies oddp)))
   (typep v2 '(vector (satisfies oddp)))
   (typep v3 '(vector (satisfies oddp)))))
```

According to the [spec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_vector.htm) the first parameter to the vector compound type denotes the element-type, thus the type specifiers above should match a vector with elements that satisfy `oddp`, right? So why are all type checks t then?!?! @_@

A solution to this could be

```
(defun vector-of-oddints-p (v)
  (and
   (vectorp v)
   (every #'(lambda (n) (and (integerp n) (oddp n))) v)))

(let ((v1 (vector 1 3))
      (v2 (vector 1 3 4))
      (v3 (vector 1 3 "4")))
  (values
   (typep v1 '(satisfies vector-of-oddints-p))
   (typep v2 '(satisfies vector-of-oddints-p))
   (typep v3 '(satisfies vector-of-oddints-p))))
```

yet this feels clunky and the above type specifier should work imo.

Comment: This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064113/how-to-specify-element-type-in-vector-of-sbcl-or-common-lisp

Comment: Call TYPE-OF on the vector and see what it returns.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig It returns simple-vector  (a subtype of vector) as expected. Not sure what that implies though.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @Halbert and @Rainer Joswig; I learned something about arrays today! <3

The type specifier `'(vector (satisfies oddp))` thus actually denotes a vector that *can* (but not necessarily and not exclusively has to) hold elements that satisfy the oddp predicate.
(cf. Rainer's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21066478/6455731)

Unsurprisingly the [spec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_array.htm#array) is actually very educational on this:

> If element-type is the symbol *, arrays are not excluded on the basis
> of their element type. Otherwise, only those arrays are included whose
> actual array element type is the result of upgrading element-type.

Also the section on [array upgrading](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/15_aba.htm) is informative, e.g. concerning the above mentioned "actual array element type":

> During creation of an array, the element type that was requested is
> called the expressed array element type. The upgraded array element
> type of the expressed array element type becomes the actual array
> element type of the array that is created.